# Внезапный Access violation Delphi 10.1 Berlin

Tags: delphi, исключения

Что за диво дивное? Падает и хоть ты стрельни. Может кто сталкивался?

```
function TUAdapter<T>.getFields: AnsiString;
var
   Props: TStringList;
   TmpStr: String;
   Res,Prop: AnsiString;
   i: integer;
begin
  try
    Props:=getProps;
    for i:= 0 to Props.Count - 1 do
    begin
      TmpStr:=''; //Падает здесь после нескольких проходов
      TmpStr:='"'+Props[i]+'"'; 
      if Res = ''
        then Res:= Res + TmpStr
        else Res:= Res + ', '+TmpStr;
    end;
    Result:= Res
  finally
    Props.Destroy;
  end;
end;


function TUAdapter<T>.GetProps: TStringList;
var
  list: TStringList;
  Props : PPropList;
  i: integer;
  propCount : integer;
begin
  if (uEntityObj.ClassInfo = nil)
    then begin
      raise Exception.Create('Not able to get properties!');
    end;
  try
    List:= TStringList.Create;
    propCount := GetPropList(uEntityObj.ClassInfo, Props);
    for i:=0 to propCount-1 do
    begin
      list.Add(Props[i].Name);
    end;
  finally
    FreeMem(Props);
  end;
  Result:= list;
end;

function GetPropList(TypeInfo: PTypeInfo; out PropList: PPropList): Integer;
begin
  Result := GetTypeData(TypeInfo)^.PropCount;
  if Result > 0 then
  begin
    GetMem(PropList, Result * SizeOf(Pointer));
    GetPropInfos(TypeInfo, PropList);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Укажите версию среды и, пожалуйста, форматните код.

Comment: зачем вы разрушаете объект, который не создавали?

Comment: @PavelMayorov может `getProps` - метод-фабрика с плохим названием

Comment: @PavelMayorov с чего вы взяли что не я его создаю? Игорь правильно подметил!

Comment: @Igor было бы так - не было бы ошибки

Comment: @Victor Вы все-таки покажите `getProps`

Comment: кто-нибудь помнит - Delphi инициализирует локальные строки (`if Res = ''`)?

Comment: @Igor подправил, И все же как мне кажется ошибка не в инициализации и заполнении листа(хотя я чего то может и упустил) С листом я работаю спокойно и доступ к нему не пропадал но вот к переменной `TmpStr` резко пропадает доступ. `TmpStr='';` вставил так для "просто так"

Comment: @Igor да, пустой строкой!

Comment: @Victor FreeMem(Props); - а кто распределяет память?

Comment: @Igor, конкретно для этого случая в методе `GetPropList` приложил к вопросу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В приведенном коде я не вижу чего-то явно неправильного - кроме вырожденных случаев, когда список свойств пустой:

```
function TUAdapter<T>.GetProps: TStringList;
...
  List:= TStringList.Create;
  propCount := GetPropList(uEntityObj.ClassInfo, Props);
  if propCount > 0 then
  try
    for i:=0 to propCount-1 do
    begin
      list.Add(Props[i].Name);
    end;
  finally
    FreeMem(Props);
  end;
  Result:= list;
end;
```

И, давайте, я заодно выскажусь по работе с памятью в `try/finally`:

```
function TUAdapter<T>.getFields: AnsiString;
var
  Props: TStringList;
  ...
begin
  Props := getProps;
  try
    ...
  finally
    Props.Free;
  end;
end;
```

`Free` проверяет `self` на `nil` перед вызовом `Destroy` - нет необходимости каждый раз проверять ссылку перед вызовом виртуального деструктора.

Если ничего не помогает, попробуйте заменить `AnsiString` на `string` и отключить оптимизацию.

Comment: А можно тогда и пояснить почему именно `free`?

Comment: @Victor добавил

Comment: Спасибо огромное!

Comment: @Victor Минутку, мне ж интересно - что помогло?

Comment: Да, но после "вкл/выкл" оно заработало и в исходном варианте)) Нужно чаще машину перегружать