# Указатели Delphi Что, Как и Почему?

Tags: delphi, указатели

Подкиньте пожалуйста пищи для ума по поводу указателей в DELPHI!
Нет, я читал конечно мат часть и работать с ними работал(не до конца понимая их природу) но зачем?

```
type TMyRec = class
  s:string;
  n:integer;
end;

var MyRec: TMyRec;
    PRec: ^TMyRec;    
begin
//Но MyRec сейчас null на какую область памяти может начать ссылаться PRec?
  PRec:=@MyRec;
  PRec^.S:='Строка данных';//С помощью указателя производится изменение строкового поля записи
  PRec^.N:=256;//С помощью указателя производится изменение числового поля записи
end;
```

Все супер, все замечательно и работает. Но зачем, если следующая запись также замечательно работает?

```
var MyRec: TMyRec;
begin
  MyRec:=TMyRec.Create;
  MyRec.S:='Строка данных';
  MyRec.N:=256;
end;
```

В общем у меня куча вопросов по указателям которые я даже сформулировать не могу 
Буду благодарен любой информации где разъясняется зачем нужны указатели в повседневной жизни

Comment: Главная задача указателей - работа с динамически выделяемой памятью, когда на этапе компиляции вы не знаете сколько именно памяти потребуется программе.

Comment: Потому что делфовый компилятор видит, что PRec - это указатель и он позволяет использовать точку. В с++ так нельзя - там можно сделать перегрузку и поведение может сильно отличаться.

Comment: @ГерманБорисов Вообще ни разу Ваш комментарий не прояснил ситуацию! Чем такая запись не устраивает? `MyRec:=TMyRec.Create;`  Я тоже не знаю сколько памяти понадобится тем не менее выделил ее !

Comment: @Kromster Пусть будет класс, а какая разница в контексте указателей?

Comment: @Victor, MyRec:=TMyRec.Create; - это выделение памяти ровно под один экземпляр TMyRec. А указатели нужны, например, когда вам нужно получать их количество из внешнего источника,такого как ввод с клавиатуры или чтение из файла.

Comment: @ГерманБорисов абсолютно согласен.

Comment: @Victor, посмотрите вот тут пример http://www.delphisources.ru/pages/faq/base/dyn_list.html

Comment: @ГерманБорисов спасибо! Но, Вопрос остался тот же - зачем там указатели? Я все тоже могу сделать без них. И если я все понимаю `new(PRec)` также выделяет память под один экземпляр!

Comment: А как вы собираетесь сделать список пар строк {Фамилия, Имя} длина которого заранее не известна и, гипотетически, не ограничена? new(PRec) - как раз и выделяет парять. А в первом вашем примере строка PRec:=@MyRec - это присвоение указателю памяти, выделенной на этапе компиляции под переменную MyRec

Comment: @ГерманБорисов все точно также вот только вместо указателей я бы создавал так`curr := TStudent.Create() ;`. Или я чего то не понимаю?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55469/discussion-between---and-victor).

Comment: не тупите. у вас тут указатель на объект (класс), который вообще референс-тип. смысла в указателях нет. Смысл появится, когда будет `record`, который надо передать по ссылке в метод.

Comment: @teran не туплю! НЕ знаю вот и спрашиваю. Мне уже объяснили спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Синоним указателя - ссылка.
Есть память, есть ссылка на память. 
При передаче `TClass` в процедурe будет передан все равно указатель (ссылка) на объект, а не сам объект.

При передаче `record` без указателя в процедурe будет передан весь кусок памяти, а не ссылка, то есть полная структура.

Указатель наследуется из Паскаля еще времён до ООП, то есть когда классов еще не было и в помине. 
В Паскале нет классов типа TList и чтобы сделать, что то аналогичное надо городить свой огород: 

`TList = record
  S : string;
  Next : pointer;
  prev : pointer; 
end;
PList = ^TList`

То есть указатели нужны преимущественно для `record` ну и для совместимости с Pascal

Comment: Так же, указатели часто нужны для примитивных типов (Integer и т.п.)

Comment: Не надо главное тут понимать под `record` исключительно то, что вы пишите в своем коде на delphi. WinApi, да и любой вообще API, чаще всего параметрами функций/методов использует структуры.

Comment: Да тут нечего понимать. Есть просто куски памяти, к которым нужен доступ. Вся специфика в том как происходит обращение  к памяти и как данные внутри памяти расположены.

Answer (score 3):

Остановимся на

> //Но MyRec сейчас null

и

> Все супер, все замечательно и работает.

Локальная переменная `MyRec` до присвоения - не `nil`, а имеет произвольное значение (мусор). Вам просто повезло, так как в следующих строчках Вы пишите в произвольную область памяти, и последствия этого могут быть самые неожиданные.

Помните, в [Внезапный Access violation Delphi 10.1 Berlin](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/639366) я изменил Ваш код

```
try
  Props:=getProps;
  ... 
finally
  Props.Destroy;
end;
```

вынеся присвоение за `try`

```
Props := getProps;
try
  ... 
finally
  Props.Free;
end;
```

Смысл строчки, присваивающей значение `Props` вне блока `try/finally` в том, что в случае исключения внутри `getProps`, внутрь `finally` код не попадет, и не будет попытки освободить память, на которую указывает неинициализированная локальная переменная `Props`.

Другой *правильный* вариант:

```
Props := nil;
try
  Props := getProps;
  ... 
finally
  Props.Free;
end;
```